# Convert Blob content into CSV format in java

Tags: java, arrays, csv

I want to read Blob content store in database, and write it to HttpServletResponse in CSV format in java. When I try to write byte[] of CSV content which is stored in Blob to the response, the CSV file content is getting corrupted.

Please suggest if you have any idea.

Thanks

Comment: How are you doing that?

Comment: Have you set the Content-Type?

Comment: with the charset?

Comment: Blob just means any binary data, so it could be anything. You have to use your knowledge about the data to parse/deserialize/unmarshall it. Then you can use something like https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/ to write the CSV file.

Comment: Or just use a string builder and write to a file.

Comment: you should've added some code snippet which describes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I've done that:

```
private static void sendResponse(Connection con, long id,
        HttpServletResponse resp, String filename) {
    try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(
            "select CONTENT_TYPE,CONTENT "
                    + "from CONTENT_TABLE "
                    + "where ID=?")) {
        int ix = 0;
        stmt.setLong(++ix, id);
        try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
            if (rs.next()) {
                String type = rs.getString(1);
                Blob result = rs.getBlob(2);
                if (result != null) {
                    try (InputStream in = result.getBinaryStream()) {
                        resp.setContentType(type);
                        resp.setCharacterEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
                        resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                                        "attachment;filename=" + filename);
                        resp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public");
                        resp.setHeader("Pragma","");  
                        OutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();
                        try {
                            byte buf[] = new byte[4096];
                            for (int n = in.read(buf); n > 0; n = in.read(buf)) {
                                out.write(buf, 0, n);
                            }
                        } finally {
                            out.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException | IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please can let me know what would be the content type in your sample code(resp.setContentType(type)).

Comment: It can be anything. If the content is CSV, the mime type is "text/csv".

Comment: I found the root cause for this, there was an issue while storing the content in Blob itself. Anyhow thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do this is to convert your binary data to a Base 64 string representation.

[Apache commons codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) does this for you:

Just use:

```
byte[] binaryData = someMethodToReadYourFileIntoBytes();
String encodedData = Base64.encodeBase64String(binaryData);`
//now just write that to your CSV output.
```

Refer to the [javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeBase64String-byte:A-) for more information and other options on how to go about it.

Hope it helps.